# What's a namespace used for in the App Engine datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, namespaces

In the development admin console, when I look at my data, it says "`Select different namespace`".

What are namespaces for and how should I use them?

Answer (score 13):

Namespaces allow you to implement segregation of data for multi-tenant applications.  The [official documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy/overview.html) links to some sample projects to give you an idea how it might be used.

Answer (score 1):

**Namespaces is used in google app engine to create Multitenant Applications. In Multitenent applications single instance of the application runs on a server, serving multiple client organizations (tenants). With this, an application can be designed to virtually partition its data and configuration (business logic), and each client organization works with a customized virtual application instance..you can easily partition data across tenants simply by specifying a unique namespace string for each tenant.**

Other Uses of namespace:

1. Compartmentalizing user information
2. Separating admin data from application data
3. Creating separate datastore instances for testing and production
4. Running multiple apps on a single app engine instance

For More information visit the below links:

```
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/12/multitenancy-in-google-appengine-gae.html
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/
http://java.dzone.com/articles/multitenancy-google-appengine

http://www.sitepoint.com/multitenancy-and-google-app-engine-gae-java/
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking, towards this question is not that much good reviewed and answered so trying to give this one.

When using namespaces, we can have a best practice of key and value separation there on a given namespace. Following is the best example of giving the namespace information thoroughly.

```
from google.appengine.api import namespace_manager
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

class Counter(db.Model):
   """Model for containing a count."""
   count = db.IntegerProperty()


def update_counter(name):
   """Increment the named counter by 1."""
def _update_counter(name):
   counter = Counter.get_by_key_name(name)
   if counter is None:
       counter = Counter(key_name=name);
       counter.count = 1
   else:
       counter.count = counter.count + 1
   counter.put()
# Update counter in a transaction.
db.run_in_transaction(_update_counter, name)

class SomeRequest(webapp.RequestHandler):
 """Perform synchronous requests to update counter."""
 def get(self):
    update_counter('SomeRequest')
    # try/finally pattern to temporarily set the namespace.
    # Save the current namespace.
    namespace = namespace_manager.get_namespace()
    try:
        namespace_manager.set_namespace('-global-')
        update_counter('SomeRequest')
    finally:
        # Restore the saved namespace.
        namespace_manager.set_namespace(namespace)
    self.response.out.write('<html><body><p>Updated counters')
    self.response.out.write('</p></body></html>')
```